# expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token while cmake, but not while pure g++ compilation

Tags: g++

i am just found for myself "cmake". And now trying to implement it to my few old programs. But now, i encounter this error while compiling with cmake:

cd project directory

cmake.

make - and here error is thrown "expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token, TString(TString &&_obj);"

But, if i compile this program with:

g++ program.cpp -o program -std=c++11 - it compiles correctly without errors.

I am on Ubuntu(gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)
I don't clearly understand what's wrong. 
Here is my code:

string.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "TString.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  long n;
  std::cout << "\n Enter num to initialize binstring" << '\n';
  std::cin >> n;
  TBinString bin(n);
  std::cout << "\n Your number in bin" << '\n';
  TBinString bin2(bin);
  std::cout << bin2.GetString() << '\n';
  bin2 ="101";
  std::cout << "\nAdding 5 to your number" << '\n';
  bin += bin2;
  std::cout << bin.GetString() << '\n';



  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

TString.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class TString {
protected:
  char *str;
  int size;
  inline void eat_rest();
public:
  TString();
  TString(int);
  TString(const char*);
  TString(TString &_obj);
  TString(TString &&_obj);
  ~TString();

  void Set(const char*);
  const char* GetString() const;
  int GetSize() const;
  int Len();
  void Clear();

  void operator=(const TString &_obj);
  void operator+=(const TString &_obj);
  void operator+=(const char*);
  TString operator+(const TString &_obj);
  TString operator+(const char*);
  friend bool operator == (const TString &_left, const TString &_right);
  friend bool operator != (const TString &_left, const TString &_right);
};

class TBinString : public TString{
public:
  TBinString();
  TBinString(long);
  TBinString(const char*);
  TBinString(TBinString &);
  TBinString(TBinString &&);
  ~TBinString();

  void Sign();
  int FindBits(long);
  TBinString Sum(const char*);

  void operator=(const TBinString &_obj);
  TBinString operator+(TBinString &);
  TBinString operator+(const char*);
  TBinString operator+(const long);
  void operator+=(const TString &);
  void operator+=(const char*);
  void operator+=(const long);
};
```

TString.cpp

```
#include "TString.h"

TString::TString(int n){
  this->str = new char[n];
  this->size = n;
}
TString::TString():TString(80){}
TString::TString(const char* str):TString(strlen(str)+1){
  //strncpy(this->str, str, this->size);
  strcpy_s(this->str, this->size, str);
}
TString::TString(TString &_obj):TString(_obj.size){
  //strncpy(this->str, _obj.str, this->size);
  strcpy_s(this->str, this->size, _obj.str);
}
TString::TString(TString &&_obj){
  this->str = _obj.str;
  _obj.str = NULL;
  this->size = _obj.size;
  _obj.size = 0;
}
TString::~TString(){
  delete [] str;
}

void TString::Set(const char *_str){
  delete [] this->str;
  this->str = new char[strlen(_str)+1];
  this->size = strlen(_str)+1;
  //strncpy(this->str, _str, this->size);
  strcpy_s(this->str, this->size, _str);
}
const char* TString::GetString() const{
  if (this->str == NULL) {
    return "<string is empty>";
  }
  return this->str;
}
int TString::GetSize() const{
  return this->size;
}

int TString::Len(){
  return strlen(this->str);
}
void TString::Clear(){
  this->Set("");
}

void TString::operator=(const TString &_obj){
  this->Set(_obj.str);
}

TString TString::operator+(const TString &_obj){
  char *buff = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(_obj.str) + 1];
  size_t size = strlen(this->str) + strlen(_obj.str) + 1;
  buff[0] = 0;
  //strncat(buff, this->str, size);
  strcat_s(buff, size, this->str);
  //strncat(buff, _obj.str, size);
  strcat_s(buff, size, _obj.str);
  TString ret(buff);
  return ret;
}
TString TString::operator+(const char *_obj){
  char *buff = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(_obj) + 1];
  size_t size = strlen(this->str) + strlen(_obj) + 1;
  buff[0] = 0;
  //strncat(buff, this->str, size);
  strcat_s(buff, size, this->str);
  //strncat(buff, _obj.str, size);
  strcat_s(buff, size, _obj);
  TString ret(buff);
  return ret;
}

void TString::operator+=(const TString &_obj){
  *this = *this + _obj;
}
void TString::operator+=(const char *_obj){
  *this = *this + _obj;
}

bool operator == (const TString &_left, const TString &_right){
  if (_left.GetSize() == _right.GetSize()) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _left.GetSize(); i++) {
      if (_left.GetString()[i] != _right.GetString()[i])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }else
    return false;
}
bool operator!=(const TString &_left, const TString &_right){
  return !(_left == _right);
}

void TString::eat_rest(){
  while (std::cin.get() != '\n') ;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class TBinString

TBinString::TBinString(){
  this->str = NULL;
  this->size = 0;
}
TBinString::TBinString(long n):TBinString(){
  this->size = this->FindBits(n) +2; //one for sign and one fo \0
  this->str = new char[this->size];
  this->str[0] = '0';
  long m = abs(n);
  for (size_t i = this->size-2; i > 0; i--) {
    this->str[i] = (m % 2) + '0';
    m /= 2;
  }
  this->str[this->size-1] = '\0';
  if (n < 0)
    this->Sign();//доп. код

}
TBinString::TBinString(const char* _str):TBinString(){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(_str); i++) {
    if (_str[i] != '1' && _str[i] != '0') {
      this->str = NULL;
      this->size = 0; //one for \0
      return;
    }
  }
  this->size = strlen(_str) +1; //one for \0
  this->str = new char[this->size];
  //strncpy(this->str, _str, this->size);
  strcpy_s(this->str, this->size, _str);
}
TBinString::TBinString(TBinString &_obj):TBinString(){
  this->size = _obj.size; //one for \0
  this->str = new char[this->size];
  //strncpy(this->str, _obj.str, this->size);
  strcpy_s(this->str, this->size, _obj.str);
}
TBinString::TBinString(TBinString &&_obj):TBinString(){
  this->size = _obj.size; //one for \0
  this->str = _obj.str;
  _obj.str = NULL;
}
TBinString::~TBinString(){}

int TBinString::FindBits(long n){
  int ret = 0;
  n = abs(n);
  while (n > 0) {
    n = n /2; ret++;
  }
  return ret;
}

void TBinString::Sign(){
  this->str[0] = '1';
  //inverting
  for (size_t i = this->size-2; i > 0; i--) {
    if (this->str[i] == '0')
    this->str[i] = '1';
    else
    this->str[i] = '0';
  }
  //adding 1
  for (size_t i = this->size-2; i > 0; i--) {
    if (this->str[i] == '0'){
      this->str[i] = '1';
      break;
    }
    else
    this->str[i] = '0';
  }
}

TBinString TBinString::Sum(const char *_str){
  bool over = false;
  int size_left = this->size;
  int size_right = strlen(_str)+1;
  TBinString buff;
  buff.size = size_left > size_right ? size_left : size_right;
  size_left -= 2; size_right -= 2;
  int i = buff.size-2;
  buff.str = new char[buff.size];
  for (;size_left >= 0 && size_right >= 0; i--, size_left--, size_right--) {
    if (this->str[size_left] == '1') {
      if (_str[size_right] == '0'){
        if (over)
          buff.str[i] = '0';
        else
          buff.str[i] = '1';
      }
      else{//_str[size_right] == '1'
        if (over)
          buff.str[i] = '1';
        else{
          buff.str[i] = '0';
          over = true;
        }
      }
    }else{//this->str[size_left] == '0'
      if (_str[size_right] == '0') {
        if (over) {
          buff.str[i] = '1';
          over = false;
        }
        else
          buff.str[i] = '0';
      }else{//_str[size_right] == '1'
        if (over)
          buff.str[i] = '0';
        else
          buff.str[i] = '1';
      }
    }
  }
  while (size_left >= 0) {
    if (this->str[size_left] == '1') {
      if (over)
        buff.str[i] = '0';
      else
        buff.str[i] = '1';
    }else{//this->str[size_left] == '0'
      if (over) {
        buff.str[i] = '1';
        over = false;
      }else
        buff.str[i] = '0';
    }
    size_left--; i--;
  }
  while (size_right >= 0) {
    if (_str[size_right] == '1') {
      if (over)
        buff.str[i] = '0';
      else
        buff.str[i] = '1';
    }else{//_str[size_right] == '0'
      if (over) {
        buff.str[i] = '1';
        over = false;
      }else
        buff.str[i] = '0';
    }
    size_right--; i--;
  }
  buff.str[buff.size-1] = '\0';
  return buff;
}

void TBinString::operator=(const TBinString &_obj){
  this->Set(_obj.str);
}

TBinString TBinString::operator+(TBinString &_obj){
  return this->Sum(_obj.GetString());
}
TBinString TBinString::operator+(const char *_str){
  return this->Sum(_str);
}
TBinString TBinString::operator+(const long _var){
  TBinString tmp(_var);
  return this->Sum(tmp.GetString());
}
void TBinString::operator+=(const TString &_obj){
  *this = this->Sum(_obj.GetString());
}
void TBinString::operator+=(const char *_str){
  *this = this->Sum(_str);
}
void TBinString::operator+=(const long _var){
  TBinString tmp(_var);
  *this = this->Sum(tmp.GetString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, when writing question. Sorry for that! 
You need to add standart c++11 flag when compiling with cmake